# Force end of turn even if units still have move points

Tags: civilization-6, keyboard

I am just in the tutorial game in Civilization VI. What shall I click to force end of turn even if some units still have move points?

Or at least how can I skip the unit marking "this turn do nothing"?

Note:

- space has no effect to skip the unit as it used to have since Civ2 (anyone remembers 640x480 screen in 16 colours?)
- some other keyboard shortcuts do not work as well (only some: for example numeric + & - work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the **Skip Turn** command:

[image: Screenshot of the skip turn button]

When you select a unit, its command window will open in the lower right corner of the screen. On top of that window, you can see various buttons, including the Skip Turn button, which looks like a curved arrow.

Interestingly, according to https://www.en.magicgameworld.com/sid-meiers-civilization-vi-pc-controls-shortcut-keys/ the <kbd>space</kbd> key should be the proper shortcut for Skip Turn.

If you want a unit to skip many turns, you can choose the **Sleep** button <kbd>Z</kbd> or the **Fortify** button <kbd>F</kbd> instead.

Comment: You can also use Shift + Enter to force end your turn.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Space is indeed defined in game options, but for some reasons selected shortcuts do not work. Not sure why.

Comment: I noticed, that Space works 100% on civilians, but on other units it works only if unit spent at least one move point i.e. militaries with full movement can't skip turn and have to use Alert, Sleep, Fortify or Fortify unitl Healed